# Python - get dict's keys' values if matching specific name

Tags: python

I have two list comprehensions that do exactly same thing but differ in one dict's element - key of `stopped` and `warning`.

```
logs_warning = [
    DDLog(self.HOST, "dms", log["name"], log["StopReason"], f"env:{env}").to_log()
    for env in self.envs
    for log in tasks[env]["warning"]["tasks"]
]

logs_stopped = [
    DDLog(self.HOST, "dms", log["name"], log["StopReason"], f"env:{env}").to_log()
    for env in self.envs
    for log in tasks[env]["stopped"]["tasks"]
]
```

I'm trying to get a `or` like logic to pick any of above keys. Trick is that `key` element is in the middle part of my selection so below didn't work:

```
for log in [tasks.get(env) for key in ['stopped', 'warning']]
```

What I'm aiming at is below (pseudo code):

```
tasks[env]["stopped" OR "warning"]["tasks"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an additional for-loop in the list comprehension:

```
logs_stopped = [
    DDLog(self.HOST, "dms", log["name"], log["StopReason"], f"env:{env}").to_log()
    for env in self.envs
    for key in ("warning", "stopped")
    for log in tasks[env][key]["tasks"]
]
```

Comment: Right... now I see that I already have two `for` statements in my list comp. Thanks, always a learning opportunity!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? I tried to translate the pseudocode to actually working code, assuming that you know how those dictionaries work and one of "stopped" or "warning" always exists.

```py
(tasks[env].get("stopped") or tasks[env].get("warning"))["tasks"]
```

if you need both of them, the logic is not OR, it's more like AND :D

```py
tasks[env]["stopped"]["tasks"]+tasks[env]["warning"]["tasks"]
```

i assume these are lists, and if not you can convert them with list() in order to succeed at adding them

Comment: Yes but it returns only `stopped` even when `warning` is also present in the dict.